# Site renders incorrectly in iOS (safari and chrome) and android (chrome)

Tags: ios, css

My site http://lapointcomm.com/work/sweek-slider/ renders correctly on my desktop browsers but something goes haywire when in safari or chrome on my iOS devices, as well as an android tablet.

I'm not a knowledgeable developer.

Comment: Please elaborate on 'haywire'.  You mean the text doesn't line up with the gap in the image?  That happens on desktop too.

Comment: what browser and system are you using?

Comment: Windows: Chrome, Firefox, Safari, IE, Opera.  I have a 1600x900 screen.

Comment: @Mark, try using meta- ta to set device width or try adding seperate css for each .